# Obtener variables GET con ruta amigable

Tags: javascript, php, html

Quisiera enviar un parámetro id hacia otra vista, pero me sale el error que no me reconoce el parámetro, atraves de este codigo envio mi id:

```
 <a href="archivo?id=$' . $row["idExpediente"] . '" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i></button></a>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y trato de recibirlo con un  `echo $_GET["id"];`

tengo mi archivo .htaccess con el siguiente código, lo que hace un ruta amigable.

```
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

Comment: Y en que momento estás enviando el dato ?

Comment: lo que quiero es obtener la variable de mi url

Comment: Desde una tabla, desde otro formulario obtengo el id, trato de enviar el id atraves de la url

Comment: Veré si continúo luego, pero testeando `<?php
echo $_GET["id"];
?>` para la url -> test.php?id=1 ... estoy obteniendo 1... debe ser un error tipográfico. -> imagen -> https://gyazo.com/3a84ca1a9ef07487e247f7db17ebcd19

Comment: `<a href="archivo?id=$'` Este es tu codigo... por que hay un signo $ ahi ?

Comment: estaba probando varias cosas, en realidad lo tengo así =" href="archivo?id=' . $row["idExpediente"] . '""

Comment: Ahí te han encontrado el error, recuerda marcar la respuesta si es que ha servido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He visto tu problema y he probado la url con la herramienta de testeo de .htaccess, La regla que es implementado funciona correctamente.
puedes probarla [aqui](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Recuerda que una url amigable es algo asi https://midominio.com/mesadepartes/51

Bueno como repuesta a tu error estas intentando imprimir una variable que previamente has renombrado con el htaceess

Es decir la variable que debes imprimir no es $_GET["id"]  si no que debes imprimir $_GET['ruta']

Ya que la renombras aqui `RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1`

--------------------------------------------EDITO--------------------------------

Aunque con esa regla recibiras toda la url al momento de imprimir `$_GET['url']`

La opción que tienes, es que cambies la regla del htaccess a algo asi:

```
RewriteRule ^mesadepartes/([0-9]*)$ index.php?ruta=$1 [L,NC]
```

Donde `([0-9]*)` (cualquier numero enviado) se convertirar en `$_GET["ruta"]`

El enlace `<a>` deberia ser de la siguiente manera

```
echo "<a href='mesadepartes/" . $row["idExpediente"] . "' target='_blank'><button class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fas fa-file-pdf'></i></button></a>";
```

Si "mesadepartes" es el nombre del producto o algo por el estilo tambien podrias meterlo en una variable y sustituirlo en el `htaccess` la regla quedaria de la siguiente manera.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]*)/([0-9]*)$ index.php?producto=$1&ruta=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: al momento de imprimir $_GET['ruta'] me imprime solo la ruta, mas no la id :C

Comment: He editado la respuesta

Comment: SI te ha servido el codigo, puedes cerrar la pregunta